# How do I convert a decimal exponent like e+308 (in base 10) to a hexadecimal number with equivalent magnitude?

Tags: c++, find, hex, decimal, exponent

Say, I have the number 0.1e+308. How can I take the exponent 308 (which is base 10), and find the correct exponent in hexadecimal (base 16)?

I don't simply mean convert 308 to hexadecimal. - That's easy!  I want to find the equivalent hexadecimal number for e308.

I need this because I have a routine which adds the correct number of zeros to the end of a number.  I used decimal (base 10) but my routine takes too long (~20 seconds) to find the answer.

But, if I use hexadecimal I can find the result in less than a second.  Because converting base 16 to binary is very fast.

The numbers I'm calculating are quite large, so think of something like BigInteger. But I'm coding it in C++.

**EDIT 1**

This is my routine for converting a decimal string in to binary bit array.

```
case 10:
    bitsSum = bits_duplicate(bitsDst);
    if (bitsSum == NULL)
        goto error;
    bitsTen = bits_create_value(maxBits, 10);
    if (bitsTen == NULL)
        goto error;
    int len = str_chars_length(strDup);
    char c;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = strDup[i] - '0';
        if (c == 0)
            continue;
        if (bits_set(bitsSum, c) == 0)
            goto error;
        for (k = 0; k < len - i - 1; k++) {
            if (bits_multiply(bitsTen, bitsSum) == 0)
                goto error;
        }
        if (bits_add(bitsSum, bitsDst) == 0)
            goto error;
    }
    break;
```

You can clearly see that converting a string value in to a equivalent binary array is slow because it requires multiplication and addition.

But my routine for converting a hexadecimal string in to a binary bit array is very fast:

```
        d = ((strDup[i] >= '0' && strDup[i] <= '9') ? strDup[i] - '0' : (strDup[i] >= 'a' && strDup[i] <= 'f') ? strDup[i] - 'a' + 10 : strDup[i] - 'A' + 10);
        bitsDst->bitArray[k++] = (d & 1) ? 1 : 0;
        bitsDst->bitArray[k++] = (d & 2) ? 1 : 0;
        bitsDst->bitArray[k++] = (d & 4) ? 1 : 0;
        bitsDst->bitArray[k++] = (d & 8) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Can you code it using [calc](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/calc/) or `Python` instead?  Or do you have to use C++?

Comment: I can use C or C++, or if you have an example in any other language I'm sure I could take that an convert it myself.

Comment: This question is entirely unclear. Can you post the slow decimal function so we can understand what it is you're trying to do. Your explanation says you've tried using decimal numbers but want to use hexadecimal numbers. All numbers are binary inside the computer. Are you using strings? How is your data formatted?

Comment: I have an exponent in decimal and I want the equivalent exponent but in hexadecimal.  I'll see if I can post some code.

Comment: You can't.  Consider the numbers 0.1E1 and 0.15E2. They have a decimal exponent of 1 and 2 although their hexadecimal representations have both an hexadecimal exponent of 1.

Comment: @AProgrammer an approximation would do as well.

Comment: Then see @user3344003 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

0.1e+308 = 10^307

Log10 (10^307) = 307

Log16 (10^307) = Log10(10^307) / Log10(16)  = 307 / Log10(16)

Comment: Thank you!  I think this is the answer I was looking for.